# Maven spring dependency issue

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, dependency-injection, pom.xml

I have added a dependency in my application towards a component that is based on springboot, I 'm getting this exception when trying to deploy at my application startup , the dependendy i'm trying to add is for internal component that is build on spring , we do have other dependencies towards others compnent based on spring

Parent POM

```
<vehicle.client.version>19</vehicle.client.version>
```

Sub POM

```
  <dependency>
                <groupId>x</groupId>
                <artifactId>vehicleclient-impl-jms</artifactId>
                <version>${vehicle.client.version}</version>
            </dependency>
```

stacktrace

```
[org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext] | Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'documentationPluginsBootstrapper' defined in URL [jar:file:ct-gw-gateway-deployable/0-SNAPSHOT/runtime/jar/application/ct-gw-gateway-app-0-SNAPSHOT.war!/WEB-INF/lib/springfox-spring-web-2.6.1.jar!/springfox/documentation/spring/web/plugins/DocumentationPluginsBootstrapper.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'webMvcRequestHandlerProvider' defined in URL [jar:file:/opt/gw/ct-gw-gateway-deployable/0-SNAPSHOT/runtime/jar/application/ct-gw-gateway-app-0-SNAPSHOT.war!/WEB-INF/lib/springfox-spring-web-2.6.1.jar!/springfox/documentation/spring/web/plugins/WebMvcRequestHandlerProvider.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'requestMappingHandlerMapping' defined in com.wirelesscar.componentbase.web.EnablegwWebMvcConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ambiguous mapping. Cannot map 'swagger2ProxySupportController' method
    public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<springfox.documentation.spring.web.json.Json> com.wirelesscar.componentbase.apidocumentation.swagger.Swagger2ProxySupportController.getDocumentation2(java.lang.String,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
    to {[/support-tool-support/api-docs],methods=[GET]}: There is already 'swagger2SupportToolSupportController' bean method
    public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<springfox.documentation.spring.web.json.Json> com.wirelesscar.componentbase.apidocumentation.swagger.Swagger2SupportToolSupportController.getDocumentation(java.lang.String,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest) mapped.
    2017-03-31 13:40:53.710 [E] [                                ] [org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication] | Application startup failed
    org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'documentationPluginsBootstrapper' defined in URL [jar:file:/opt/gw/ct-gw-gateway-deployable/0-SNAPSHOT/runtime/jar/application/ct-gw-gateway-app-0-SNAPSHOT.war!/WEB-INF/lib/springfox-spring-web-2.6.1.jar!/springfox/documentation/spring/web/plugins/DocumentationPluginsBootstrapper.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'webMvcRequestHandlerProvider' defined in URL [jar:file:/opt/gw/ct-gw-gateway-deployable/0-SNAPSHOT/runtime/jar/application/ct-gw-gateway-app-0-SNAPSHOT.war!/WEB-INF/lib/springfox-spring-web-2.6.1.jar!/springfox/documentation/spring/web/plugins/WebMvcRequestHandlerProvider.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'requestMappingHandlerMapping' defined in com.wirelesscar.componentbase.web.EnablegwWebMvcConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ambiguous mapping. Cannot map 'swagger2ProxySupportController' method
    public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<springfox.documentation.spring.web.json.Json> com.wirelesscar.componentbase.apidocumentation.swagger.Swagger2ProxySupportController.getDocumentation2(java.lang.String,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
    to {[/support-tool-support/api-docs],methods=[GET]}: There is already 'swagger2SupportToolSupportController' bean method
    public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<springfox.documentation.spring.web.json.Json> com.wirelesscar.componentbase.apidocumentation.swagger.Swagger2SupportToolSupportController.getDocumentation(java.lang.String,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest) mapped.
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:749) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.4.RELEASE]
```

Comment: can you update question with `pom.xml` and on which `mvn` command you getting the exception.

Comment: It seems like you have some conflict in the swagger beans, like trying to instantiate two spring beans of the same type. What dependency have you added?

Comment: @OlgaMaciaszek , I have updated my post

Comment: @AmitK I have updated my post

Comment: @Soumia , please provide your complete pom.

Comment: Problem solved, I have excluded spring dependency when adding new dependency for my component